# How to change the color of label after figure and table in the context?

Tags: color

I wanna write "Figure 1.1" in `lyx`. I can change the `color` of "figure" through `text style>>customize`, but the "1.1" always appears in black and I wanna have both of them in blue. How I can do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

With `caption` package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=blue}   %% ,textfont=blue will make all blue
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Adding `,textfont=blue` makes every thing blue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=blue,textfont=blue}   %% ,textfont=blue will make all blue
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{some caption}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want link colors also in blue, use `hyperref` and its `\autoref` command

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{caption,xcolor}
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\color{blue}}
\captionsetup[figure]{labelfont=blue,textfont=blue}   %% ,textfont=blue will make all blue
\begin{document}
  \begin{figure}
    \caption{some caption}\label{fig:some}
  \end{figure}
  \autoref{fig:some}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works for the captions of figures and tables. What about in the context of the article?

Comment: @hamidrezalashgari You mean the color of `some caption`? Use `textfont=blue` inside the option.

Comment: After inserting a figure in the article, I put a label at the end of the caption for referencing in the body of the article. Now, I wanna change the color of the label in the manuscript but it appears all in black. For example, in the article let's say I wanna say " as shown in Figure 1.1". The color of "Figure" can easily be changed but "1.1" is in the form of label that I have added through cross-referencing, and always is black which doesn't give any good image to the pdf after being compiled up.

Comment: @hamidrezalashgari: Use `hyperref` and its `\autoref` as in the last code.